# Sending POST request with HTTPBuilder without waiting for a response

Tags: post, groovy, httprequest

I have this code:

```
ApiConsumer(String url) {
    this.baseUrl = url
    this.httpBuilder = initializeHttpBuilder()
    this.cookies = []
}

private HTTPBuilder initializeHttpBuilder() {
    def httpBuilder = new HTTPBuilder(baseUrl)
    httpBuilder.handler.success = { HttpResponseDecorator resp, reader ->
        resp.getHeaders('Set-Cookie').each {
            String cookie = it.value.split(';')[0]
            cookies.add(cookie)
        }
        return convertPlain("${reader}")
    }
    return httpBuilder
}

public def requestXML(Method method, ContentType contentType, String url, String bodyXML) {
    httpBuilder.parser.'application/xml' = httpBuilder.parser.'text/plain'
    httpBuilder.request(method, contentType) { request ->
        uri.path = url
        body = bodyXML
        headers['Cookie'] = cookies.join(';')
    }
}
```

Basically, with `requestXML(...)` it sends a XML request to a specified URL using HTTPBuilder for Groovy.
I'm using this code (with other minor functions) to send a request to a service, and it works.
But now I want to reuse it to make a POST request to another service that responds about 30 minutes later because this WPS service runs a program and waits the end of it. How can I send this POST request without waiting for a response?

I need to setup a timeout?
I tried to remove the `httpBuilder.handler.success` closure with no success.
Also I cannot change the way that the WPS service handle the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `AsyncHttpBulder` as described here:

[Groovy AsyncHttpBulder](https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder/wiki/AsyncHTTPBuilder)

For example:

```
import groovyx.net.http.AsyncHTTPBuilder
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.HTML

def http = new AsyncHTTPBuilder(
            poolSize : 4,
            uri : 'http://hc.apache.org',
            contentType : HTML )


def result = http.get(path:'/') { resp, html ->
    println ' got async response!'
    return html
}

assert result instanceof java.util.concurrent.Future

while ( ! result.done ) {
   println 'waiting...'
    Thread.sleep(2000)
}

/* The Future instance contains whatever is returned from the response
   closure above; in this case the parsed HTML data: */
def html = result.get()
assert html instanceof groovy.util.slurpersupport.GPathResult
```